# MYSQL error with Python

Tags: python, mysql

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
        currentid = str(row[0])


links = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'lightboxImage'})
for link in links:
        file_name = urllib2.unquote(url).decode('utf8').split('/')[-1]
        #print ("<img src=\"http:" + str(link['href'] + "\"</img>"))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `Images`(`ImageURL`, `ProductID`) VALUES (" + "\"" + file_name + "\"" + " , " + currentid)
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run it.

```
root@eBayFileServer:~# python scrape.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 102, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `Images`(`ImageURL`, `ProductID`) VALUES (" + "\"" + file_name + "\"" + " , " + currentid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

I have tried all sorts of things, like changing the quotes around the data, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `VALUES (` lacks a corresponding close paren `)` at the end.

Comment: I added quotes around the paren to inc it, but get 

                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need a `)` both in quotes and out of quotes. `+ ")")`. The first one is for MySql, the second one is for Python.

Comment: Just spot that :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `Images`(`ImageURL`, `ProductID`) VALUES (" + "'" + file_name + "'" + " , " + currentid+");")
```

you can use single quotes so you don't need to escape double quotes and close the bracket from VALUES